# Rails 4 Could not dump table "users" because of following NoMethodError # undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I started getting an error in the schema.rb file when i ran this migration below. I was following a tutorial for UUID [(tutorial)](http://blog.lingohub.com/developers/2013/10/dev-bit-auto-generate-uuid-postgres-rails-4/) and I'm not sure if this was right. I have it working fine but i cant see the table in the schema.rb file and i cant run rake db:rollback.

```
 class AddUuidToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
   add_column :users, :uuid, :uuid
  end

 def down
   remove_column :users, :uuid
 end
end
```

This is the error when i run rake db:rollback

```
undefined method `to_sym' for    nil:NilClass/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Sites/ubergradd/db/migrate/20141024175231_add_uuid_to_users.rb:7:in `down'
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Sites/ubergradd/db/migrate/20141024175231_add_uuid_to_users.rb:7:in `down'
```

In my schema.rb file

```
 # Could not dump table "users" because of following NoMethodError
 #   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Please add information when you get error mentioned in title and what tutorial you've been following. What happens when you run ````rake db:rollback````?

Comment: I added more information to the question.

Comment: And you're using postgres with added extensions? Which Rails 4 version? When you look into database (using psql command for example) do you see this column in users table?

Comment: Im using Rails 4.1.4. When i look into the database using the command i can see the column in the users table.

Comment: It seems very similar to this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893326/rails-4-schema-db-shows-could-not-dump-table-events-because-of-following-nom Are you **100** percent sure, that you've enabled uuid-ossp extenstion on your local postgres instantion?